# `msbuild` command not found, but `msbuild.exe` works fine

Tags: bash, msysgit, msys

I run MSys/Bash as distributed in [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.com). I added the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` to my path, so I could run `msbuild` but it doesn't work

```
$ msbuild
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe: msbuild: command not found
```

Yet `msbuild.exe` does:

```
$ msbuild.exe
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
```

Yet the command `explorer` resolves fine. What's going on?

Comment: Other folk have the same problem with `mplayer` under MSys http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/Directory-with-same-name-as-program-confuses-bash-td28382.html

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but msbuild.exe also do not work. I tried both answeres but only when I call the msbuild.exe directly by its full Path then it works.

Comment: I had to resort to writing an alias into .bashrc

Comment: Add msbuild.exe to your system PATH variable. That worked for me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a bug in MSys where the same name is shared by a folder and a file (minus the extension). In this case:

- File `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`
- Folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild`

You'll have to workaround by writing `msbuild.exe`

Comment: You can also work around this by making a link named `msbuild` to `msbuild.exe`, in a directory that precedes the `...\Framework\v4.0.30319` directory in `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

If the exe file outputs not found, do `copy C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe ProjectPath`
And then run `msbuild.exe`

Comment: I'd rather create a symlink...

Answer (score -1):

If msbuild.exe cannot be found, it needs to be configured.

Open a command prompt and run the file vsvars32.bat located in your Visual Studio Common7/Tools folder..

i.e C:\Program Files x86\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat

This will correctly setup all the neccessary variables for msbuild.exe to be found.

Comment: This is not working on my Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013. There is also no output from the vsvars32.bat?! I have tried it also with a admin shell without success.

Comment: For me, it's now located on `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext`.