# bash: msbuild: command not found

Tags: git, bash, msbuild, mingw, git-bash

Having a problem with adding `msbuild` to git bash for Win10

already added `msbuild` to system vars and to path too

CMD `msbuild` calls fine

[already tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819294/msbuild-command-not-found-but-msbuild-exe-works-fine)

[image: Git bash msbuild]

[image: Path]
[image: system var]

Answer (score 8):

Use `msbuild.exe` in Git Bash instead of `msbuild`.

Comment: Ouch. This hurts. Really.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refer to an environment variable you need to prefix it with `$`, like `$msbuild`. I'm not sure that is the best idea though, nor modifying the system path: what if you have different versions of msbuild?

Anyway, your real problem is that the command isn't `msbuild`, it is `MSBuild.exe`. And a convenient way of adding it to the mingw environment is making sure it is already in the path before starting bash. For example, create a batch file 'msbuild-git-bash.bat' in the same directory as git-bash.bat, containing

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
git-bash.bat
```

then use that instead and type `msbu` and hit tab to get command completion:

[image]

Note this example is for VS2013, for other versions the path to vsdevcmd.bat will be different but the principle is the same. Also because of using it, nmake/cl/link/... are also all available.

Comment: It's a pretty good advice, BUT my user permissions does not allow me to execute *.bat* files. Thank you for your help, man

Comment: So you don't use git-bash.bat for starting bash but just the exe? There might be ways around that, not sure. Can you do something like `cmd /c some.bat`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for WPF development and I just wanted to build any .net framework application/library from git bash. 
So, I just copied the following files 
from:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` 
into: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` folder and it worked like a charm:

[image: Screenshot]

Then, just go to any of your `.csproj` projects and run `msbuild` command in your git bash.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cmder` with bash, then you could define an alias like

`alias msbuild='msbuild.exe'`

(the path to msbuild.exe must be already set in PATH)