# Bash file extensions

Tags: bash, msbuild, win-bash

I'm trying to learn bash. I've noticed that I can use commands on the path like `git`, `java`, `npm`, `node`, `nuget`, `paket` etc
However, some require me to type in the exe extension for example `msbuild.exe`
since `msbuild` results in the following `bash: msbuild: command not found` but `msbuild.exe` works as expected.
Why does some command require the extension and others do not?
I'm used to `cmd` where I don't need to specify the ext, is there anything I can do so that I don't need to use the extension?

Comment: win-bash was last updated in 2006... (since that is the tag, I'm assuming you are not talking about WSL bash)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg Yes sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer to this question to find answers : [`msbuild` command not found, but `msbuild.exe` works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13819294/5194836)

In short : msbuild is a directory and an executable name, so your have to provide '.exe' extension to specify it's the executabl you want to run.

Comment: Simple when you put it like that. Thanks